# Modifying html of dom element that was created after page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have two separate AJAX calls. One that gets a list of items from a txt file and creates an HTML table out of them and one that talks to a database to find how much each item costs and then lists this in the corresponding table cell for each item (I know this may sound like a strange approach, but it's a good option in our case...).

The issue is that the price is not getting written to the table since the table is created (or to be precise, the rows of the table are created) after the page loads. I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    makeItemTable();
    listPrices();
    ... 
});

function makeItemTable() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'products.php',
        type: 'GET'
        })
    .done(function(response) {
        $('.price-table > tbody').html(response); 
        })
}

function listPrices() {
    .ajax({
        url: 'prices.php',
        type: 'GET'
}) 
    .done(function(response) {
          priceData = $.parseJSON(response);
          $('.price-table tr').each(function() {
          var item = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
          if (priceData[item]) {
               var price = priceData[item];
               $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text(price);
         }       
      })
    }
```

Comment: I would combine your products.php and prices.php so you only make one request instead of two. But if that's not possible, move `listPrices()` into the success handler for the `makeItemTable()` ajax call. If you know how many columns you'll need just create empty ones then fill them in with `listPrices()`.

Comment: Good points, Jasen. Turns out the issue was actually in the PHP. Once I trimmed the trailing whitespace on each item from the txt file it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

1. Using setTimeout to check request to 'products.php' execute callback done (inside callback for request to 'prices.php')
2. Another way

   ```
   var jqxhr1 = $.ajax("products.php");
   var jqxhr2 = $.ajax("prices.php");
   $.when(jqxhr1, jqxhr2).done(function(jqxhr1, jqxhr2) {
    // Handle both XHR objects
     alert("all complete");      
   });
   ```
3. Call function listPrices() inside callback request to 'products.php'

Hope to help